# Prove that $2 \cdot 16^k-3$ is squarefree

Tags: number-theory

> Is it true that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $2 \cdot 16^k-3$ is not divisible by $p^2$ for any prime $p$.

Through a lot of experimentation, the above seems to be squarefree for a lot of values. I was wondering if it is always squarefree.

Comment: How are you coming up with your conjectures?  It would seem that it is just by experimentation, but the original one fails at $k=17$, so you didn't search very far. -1  I am reminded of the old joke of the physicist checking "all odd numbers greater than $1$ are prime".  $3$ is prime, $5$ is prime, $7$ is prime, $9$ is experimental error, $11$ is prime, $13$ is prime, publish.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, but I have a new conjecture now, which is $2 \cdot 16^k-3$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yeah, but here these expressions are squarefree for a lot of values consecutively.

Comment: How many do you think is a lot?  Your original only was correct for $16$ cases. There is a question here about statements whose first failure is large that has examples much larger than that.

Comment: @RossMillikan I think this new question is correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been correctly answered

Comment: How does being correctly answered make it off-topic?

Answer (score 4):

$81^{k}-2$ is divisible by $7^2$ when $k \equiv 17 \mod 21$.

EDIT:
$3 \cdot 81^{109} - 2$ is divisible by $29^2$.

$3^2 \cdot 81^k-2$ is divisible by $7^2$ for $k \equiv 6 \mod 21$.

EDIT: 
More generally, consider $a b^k - c$ where $a,b,c$ are nonzero integers, $|b| > 1$.  Let $p$ be a prime that divides $a b^m-c$ for some $m$ but does not divide $a$ or $b$.  Let $r$ be the multiplicative period of $b$ mod $p$, i.e. the least positive integer such that $b^r - 1$ is divisible by $p$.  Then $b^{pr} \equiv 1 \mod p^2$.  It may happen that $b^r-1$ is itself divisible by $p^2$, but usually it will not be divisible by $p^2$.  Then $b^{nr}-1 \mod p^2$ for $n = 1,2,\ldots,p$ are all distinct, and are all
the multiples of $p \mod p^2$.  One of these is $-1 + c a^{-1} b^{-m} \mod p^2$.
Then $a b^{m+nr} - c = 
a b^m - c + a b^m (b^{nr} - 1) \equiv 0 \mod p^2$.

For example, consider the latest version of your question, with $a=2$, $b=16$, $c=3$.  Try $m=1$.  $2 \cdot 16-3$ is divisible by $29$.  The order of $16 \mod 29$ is $7$, but $16^7-1$ is not divisible by $29$, so we can take $p=29$ and $n=7$.
We want $n$ such that $16^{7n} \equiv  -1 + 3 \cdot 2^{-1} \cdot 16^{-1} \equiv 551 \mod 29^2 $.  By the previous paragraph, one of $1, 2, \ldots, 29$ must work, and in fact it is $n=19$.
So $2 \cdot 16^k - 3$ is divisible by $29^2$ for $k = 1+19 \cdot 7 = 134$,
and in fact for all $k \equiv 134 \mod 29 \cdot 7$.

Comment: What about $16^k-3$?

Comment: $16^4 -3$ is divisible by $71^2$.

Comment: Current score: Robert Israel 2, user19405892 0.

Comment: I am assuming that $2 \cdot 16^k-3$ and $2^2 \cdot 16^k-3$ are also not squarefree?

Comment: @user19405892: Perhaps you should state a general conjecture so that Robert can deal with it in one blow.

Comment: More examples: $16^{22}-3$ is divisible by $11^2$, $16^{31}-3$ is divisible by $13^2$, and $16^{157}-3$ is divisible by $23^2$. This stuff is straightforward to discover (and explain) by thinking $p$-adically.

Comment: $2 \cdot 16^{85}-3$ is divisible by $47^2$.  $2^2 \cdot 16^{40}-3$ is divisible by $23^2$.